# How to export Boost::Python module to Go

Tags: python, go, boost-python

I have no working code to show the output.

Requirement is to call this python module "pylib" from Go code.

Many similar posts has suggested to use os/exec (declare .so in pythonpath) to call pylib as an external process.

If such is a case, how to pass <string, object, object, dict> as arguments ?

Should object be created as struct in Go?

```
    #include <boost/python.hpp>

    #include "Bonjour.hpp"
    
    using namespace boost::python;
    
    BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pylib)
    {
        class_< Bonjour >("Bonjour", init<string, object, object, dict>())
          .def("greet", &Bonjour::greet)
          .add_property("msg", &Bonjour::get_msg, &Bonjour::set_msg);
    }
```

Boost.Python library was used as wrapper around C++ code in above example which lets you run C++ code from Python

Can anyone tell me how the same(pylib) can be called from Go? Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do something like what CGo provides to Go? Why are you showing C++ code if the library you have is Python? Is Python even needed here at all?

Comment: The actual code is written in C++ and uses Boost::Python to expose the C++ functions to an existing Python project. Instead of Python project now, I have to use Go which will import pylib. Something like what CGo provides to Go

Comment: @Amelia Top hit on google for [golang call python](https://poweruser.blog/embedding-python-in-go-338c0399f3d5). The other obvious option is to cut out the python wrapper and call your c++ code directly from go.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *automatically* communicate structured data between a process (Go) and a subprocess (Python).

The easiest and most common way to *manually* communicate data is to use standard input and standard output. Another way is to use command line arguments.

`<string, object, object, dict>` is not a type in Go. So, a bunch of plumbing has to be written by you to make this work.

The most intuitive method I can think of is to serialize a fixed model as JSON and then deserialize it in Python. Once a Python object with that model has been parsed, you may use its members as the arguments of what appears to be the constructor of the C++ object. The details of doing each of these things should be available on already-answered Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. Let me search materials based on your suggestion.